# Double integral $\iint\limits_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\, dA$ in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have the following integral

$$\iint\limits_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\, dA$$

where $D$ is the region bounded by the curves $y= \sqrt{2x-x^2}$  and $y=x$.

I'v been trying to solve it by change of variable to polar coordinates (centered at $(1,0)$) because the region looks like a circle and by some trigonometric rules I rewrite it like this

$$\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi \int_{\sec\theta}^1 r\sqrt{(x(r,\theta))^2 + (y(r,\theta))^2} \, dr\,d\theta$$

where $$x=r\cos\theta +1$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$

However, this just complicates the calculus.

Edit:

This is how the region looks.

[[image: Region bounded by <span class=]$y= \sqrt{2x-x^2}$  and $y=x$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwLnD.png)

Comment: You wrote $\displaystyle \underset{D}{\int\int},$ coded as `\underset{D} {\int\int}`. I changed that to $ \displaystyle \iint\limits_D,$ coded as `\iint\limits_D`. Contrast them:
$$
\begin{align}
& \underset{D}{\int\int} \\ {} \\
& \iint\limits_D
\end{align}
$$
Lots of LaTeX manuals can be found via Google. $\qquad$

Comment: Why do you say "weird change of variable"? Polar coordinates are far from weird.

Comment: For the parametrization $x = 1 + r\cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta$ that you used, bounds of $\theta$ is correct. But the lower bound of $r$ is not correct. It will be $y \geq x \implies r \sin \theta \geq 1 + r \cos\theta$ and so $r \geq \frac{1}{\sin\theta - \cos\theta}$

Comment: @TedShifrin I wrote "weird" beacuase I thought the change of variable wasn´t polar coordinates because the integration wasn´t easy to solve the way I wrote it. Sorry for the mischoosing of words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the line $y = x$ passes through origin and integrand is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, it is easier to use,

$x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$

Please note that for circles with center on one of the coordinate axes and the origin being a point on the circle, it is another standard parametrization that we can use.

$y \leq \sqrt{2x-x^2} \implies x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x, y \geq 0$

So in polar coordinates, semicircle can be written as, $r^2 \leq 2 r \cos\theta \ $ i.e. $r \leq 2 \cos\theta, 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Now there are two regions bound between $y = x$ and the semi-circle. The question should clarify which region it refers to. Based on your diagram, it is the shaded region to the left of $y = x$. So we have,

$y \geq x \implies \theta \geq \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ and the integral simplifies to,

$$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} r^2 \ dr \ d\theta$$

Answer (score 3):

The equation of this circle in polar coordinates is $r= 2\cos\theta.$

Notice that that implies $x^2+y^2=r^2 = 2r\cos\theta = 2x$ so that $y = \pm \sqrt{2x-x^2},$ which is how you wrote this.

The upper semicircle has $\theta$ going from $0$ to $\pi/2$ (not from $0$ to $\pi$, and not from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$). I think you're confusing this with a circle centered at the origin. Notice that $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and a ray starting at the origin, **not** between the $x$-axis and a ray starting at the center of the circle!

So you need $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} r \big( r \, dr \, d\theta\big). $